# PHP Restrict Access To Admin Page Unless Logged In

Tags: php, security

I've been thinking about methods for restricting access to admin page.
One of them was using sessions and using the next code section in the admin page:

```
if (!isset($_SESSION['is_admin'])) {
  header('Location: index.php');
  exit; 
}
```

I'd like to know if there's another method for doing it , which is considered more secure.
Every new point of view towards this issue will be considered helpful , thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sessions are secure enough (if used properly), what your doing will be fine for 99% of the time. However, there are other things you can look into, like [cookies](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_cookies.asp), which work like sessions but are stored on the users computer and expire at a certain date. Cookies are cool because they don't expire when the browser is closed, so be careful what you store in them. Another thing to consider is [SSL](https://www.digicert.com/ssl.htm). If security is your concern you can secure session data with an SSL certificate. Another thing you could do is [password protect an entire directory](http://www.thesitewizard.com/apache/password-protect-directory.shtml) with Apache or whatever server you're using.

Answer (score 1):

Your code seems to be matching your needs. I suggest to put your admin environment into a subfolder and protect the folder via .htaccess. A lot of webhosts let you do this (protect a folder) even by UI so it could be quite comfortable and is also secure.